# (String interpolation) How to save value to the session using the value from the session as key?

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have the following code that makes a simple POST request. How it should work? Before I have made a request, I generate a testing value `"orderName1"` and save it to the session. Next, I am using the function `"create"` to make the request and using the generated value in a function. And it works fine! My request is successful. As result, I have an order with a dynamically generated name `"Name_68hKl90G"`. But I want to save the `id`, returned from the server into the session. I want to use `"Name_68hKl90G"` as a `key` into the session.

**How it should work (session):**

> orderName1 -> Name_68hKl90G

> Name_68hKl90G -> 63d80b25cb6c2a7e7e845e40

**How it actually work (session):**

> orderName1 -> Name_68hKl90G

> ${orderName1} -> 63d80b25cb6c2a7e7e845e40

Code:

```
val generateStr = (symbols: Integer) => Random.alphanumeric.take(symbols).mkString

val prepareData = exec(
  session => {
    val newSession = session
      .set("orderName1", "Name_" + generateStr(8))
    newSession
  }
)

def create(name: String) = exec(
  http("Create order")
    .post("/shop/order")
    .body(StringBody(s"""{"name":"${name}"}""".stripMargin)).asJson
    .check(status.is(201))
    .check(jsonPath("$.id").saveAs(s"${name}")) 
)

val userScn = scenario("Scenario")
  .exec(
    prepareData,
    create("${orderName1}")
  )

setUp(
  userScn.inject(rampUsers(rampUpUserCount) during (rampUpDuration seconds)),
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is no need to use session value as a key for other value.
You can satisfy all needs by following code:

```
val generateStr = (symbols: Integer) => Random.alphanumeric.take(symbols).mkString

val prepareData = exec(
  session => {
    val newSession = session
      .set("orderName1", "Name_" + generateStr(8))
    newSession
  }
)

def create(name: String) = exec(
  http("Create order")
    .post("/shop/order")
    .body(StringBody(session => s"""{"name":"${session(name).as[String]}"}""".stripMargin)).asJson
    .check(status.is(201))
    .check(jsonPath("$.id").saveAs(s"${name}_id")) 
)

def rename(name: String, newName: String) = exec(
  http("Update order name")
    .patch(session => s"/shop/order/${session(name + "_id").as[String]}")
    .body(StringBody(session => s"""{"name":"${newName}"}""".stripMargin)).asJson
    .check(status.is(200))
)

val userScn = scenario("Scenario")
  .exec(
    prepareData,
    create("orderName1"),
    rename("orderName1", "New name")
  )

setUp(
  userScn.inject(rampUsers(rampUpUserCount) during (rampUpDuration seconds)),
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Answer (score 1):

```scala
def create(name: String) =
exec(
  http("Create order")
    .post("/shop/order")
    .body(StringBody(s"""{"name":"#{$name}"}""")).asJson
    .check(status.is(201))
    .check(jsonPath("$.id").saveAs("id")) 
).exec { session =>
  val nameValue = session(name).as[String]
  val id = session("id").as[String]
  session.remove("id").set(nameValue, id)
}

create("orderName1")
```

Honestly, this looks overly complicated. I don't get why you don't want to use 2 different attributes, one for the key and one for the value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it will be the same result

Comment: In this case I have following error: `01:20:55.850 [ERROR] i.g.c.a.b.SessionHookBuilder$$anon$1 - 'hook-2' crashed with 'j.u.NoSuchElementException: No attribute named '${orderName1}' is defined', forwarding to the next one`